How do I call function if .call() is undefined?
I'm trying to get different images to update when a one gets to a specific parts of a page (using this tutorial as a basis: https://github.com/the-pudding/how-to-implement-scrollytelling/tree/master/demo/scrollstory).
The function to determine what "step" of the page you're on is working, but I'm getting the error, "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')" when I try to call the function. Does anyone know how to fix this?
window.createGraphic = function(graphicSelector) {
    var graphicEl = d3.select('.graphic')
    var graphicVisEl = graphicEl.select('.graphic__vis')
    var graphicProseEl = graphicEl.select('.graphic__prose')
    var dv = document.getElementById('image')
    var img = document.createElement("IMG")
    
    // actions to take on each step of our scroll-driven story
    var steps = [
        function step0() {
            // remove all child nodes
            while (dv.hasChildNodes()) { 
                dv.removeChild(dv.lastChild); 
            } 

            img.src = "./img/spec_fic_pg_1.png";
            img.width = "100%";
            img.height = "auto";
            dv.appendChild(img);
        },

        function step1() {
            // remove all child nodes
            while (dv.hasChildNodes()) { 
                dv.removeChild(dv.lastChild); 
            } 

            img.src = "./img/spec_fic-02.png";
            img.width = "100%";
            img.height = "auto";
            dv.appendChild(img);
        },
    ]

    // update our img
    function update(step) {
        console.log(step);
        steps[step].call();
    }

This is the related HTML:
<body>
      <div class='story'>
        <h1>Disaster Tourism:</h1>
        <h2>The Deep South in 2100</h2>
        <div class='graphic'>
          <div class='graphic__prose'>
            <p class='trigger' data-step='0'>Step 1</p>
            <p class='trigger' data-step='1'>Step 2</p>
          </div>
          <div class='graphic__vis' id='image'></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src='d3.v4.min.js'></script>
      <script src='graphic.js'></script>
      <script src='jquery-3.1.1.min.js'></script>
      <script src='jquery.scrollstory.min.js'></script>
      <script>
        (function() {
    
          function scrollstory() {
            // select elements using jQuery since it is a dependency
            var $graphicEl = $('.graphic')
            var $graphicVisEl = $graphicEl.find('.graphic__vis')
    
            // viewport height
            var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight
            var halfViewportHeight = Math.floor(viewportHeight / 2)
    
            // a global function creates and handles all the vis + updates
            var graphic = createGraphic('.graphic')
    
            // handle the fixed/static position of grahpic
            var toggle = function(fixed, bottom) {
              if (fixed) $graphicVisEl.addClass('is-fixed')
              else $graphicVisEl.removeClass('is-fixed')
    
              if (bottom) $graphicVisEl.addClass('is-bottom')
              else $graphicVisEl.removeClass('is-bottom')
            }
    
            // callback function when scrollStory detects item to trigger
            var handleItemFocus = function(event, item) {
              var step = item.data.step
              graphic.update(step)
            }   
    
            // callback on scrollStory scroll event
            // toggle fixed position
            var handleContainerScroll = function(event) {
              var bottom = false
              var fixed = false
    
              var bb = $graphicEl[0].getBoundingClientRect()
              var bottomFromTop = bb.bottom - viewportHeight
    
              if (bb.top < 0 && bottomFromTop > 0) {
                bottom = false
                fixed = true
              } else if (bb.top < 0 && bottomFromTop < 0) {
                bottom = true
                fixed = false
              }
    
              toggle(fixed, bottom)
            }
    
            // instantiate scrollStory
            $graphicEl.scrollStory({
              contentSelector: '.trigger',
              triggerOffset: halfViewportHeight,
              itemfocus: handleItemFocus,
              containerscroll: handleContainerScroll,
            })
          }
    
          scrollstory()
    
        })()
      </script>
    </body>


The error doesn't mean that .call() is undefined, it means that steps[step] is undefined.

And you don't have to use .call() anyway. If steps[step] really were a function reference, you just need steps[step]()

Also it should be item.dataset[step]
